# What are the functions such that $ \lVert f + g \rVert_p^p = \lVert f \rVert_p^p + \lVert g \rVert_p^p$?

Tags: norms, functional-equations, measurable-functions

Let $1 \leq p \leq 2$. I am looking for a characterization of the couples $(f,g)$ of functions $f,g \in L_p(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$ \lVert f + g \rVert_p^p = \lVert f \rVert_p^p + \lVert g \rVert_p^p.$$

For $p = 2$, this relation is satisfied if and only if $\langle f, g \rangle = 0$. For $p = 1$, it has been shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581257/when-does-equality-hold-in-the-minkowskis-inequality-fg-p-leq-f-p-g) that the condition is equivalent to $f g \geq 0$ almost everywhere.
For a general $p$, the relation is clearly satisfied as soon as the product $fg=0$ almost everywhere. Is this latter sufficient condition also necessary?

If not, then what if we reinforce the condition with
$$ \lVert \alpha f +  \beta g \rVert_p^p = \lVert  \alpha f \rVert_p^p + \lVert \beta g \rVert_p^p$$
for any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Doesn't the rest of the linked question answer yours?

Comment: It does not because it considers the equality case in the Minkowski inequality, which corresponds to $\lVert f + g \rVert_p = \lVert f \rVert_p + \lVert g \rVert_p$, without the $p$th powers.

Comment: An important distinction with the Minkowski case is that there is no inequality between $\lVert f + g \rVert^p_p$ and $\lVert f \rVert_p^p + \lVert g \rVert_p^p$: both can be greater than the other for adequate $f,g$.